# Why do I get punished because one person decided to serial upvote me?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit, serial-voting

I get the way the system works, unfortunately it's not fair on the victim - in this case me. Here's the deal:

Today I have been serial upvoted, and have hit the rep cap as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

Fair enough, tomorrow morning in the early hours a script will run and these will be reversed - but they won't be reversed in a way that doesn't punish *me*. I get why the system is in place and I'm not disputing that, however I feel that the way the system *works* is inadequate.

Today, I have gained '200 reputation' from seemingly one user spamming me with around 20 ish upvotes in the space of 90 seconds. Tomorrow, I will lose 200 rep, this will show as a negative red bar on my profile stating serial upvoting reversed. Still fine with this.

However, today I cannot get any more legitimate upvotes, and any upvotes I get will not be offset against the 200 reputation I lose tomorrow. Additionally, if I want to repcap tomorrow, I will need to get 400 reputation.

I know this *isn't* a bug - but it feels like one. Essentially at any point in time I could go and upvote any user to the point where it will get reversed for serial upvoting, and this will prevent that user from generating any real reputation during that period of time. Surely the system should actively push back against the people who're doing this, as they're currently getting away with what is basically trolling other users anonymously.

Why do I get punished because one person decided to serial upvote me?

Comment: I don't think you *do* get punished. Any votes that weren't counted because of the rep cap will now be counted when the reversal runs. That's my understanding anyway.

Comment: No - the reversal shows as a separate line tomorrow and is nothing to do with today's reputation gains. Any additional votes gained today are essentially lost votes because one person decided to serial upvote me to the point where I rep capped.

Comment: It is not the way it works.  Just wait until tomorrow.

Comment: Never thought of a new way to punish high-rep users -> *I upvote you!*

Comment: There was some post about potential fraud targeting high-rep users, exploiting rep cup bug, but I can't find it now.

Comment: having your recalculated afterwards should probably do the trick http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All you have written is your assumption. If you have lost (not gained) actual reputation due to reputation cap because of the serial voting, tomorrow any reputation you have lost due to serial voting will be given to you.

From [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/187824)

> #### Will I get back reputation lost due to the reputation cap?
>
> Yes. Whenever serial voting gets reversed, all days involved in the
> serial voting will be recalculated as if the serial votes had never
> happened, and any reputation you might have lost due to those serial
> votes hitting the reputation cap will be given to you.

Comment: We'll know who's correct by tomorrow!

Comment: *Interesting* - this has changed since I started using SE again it seems. The last serial upvote spree against me wasn't resolved like this... Also please note, hims056, since the system used to work like this and I have quit and been undeleted since, this is not "my assumption" - this is how it used to work.

Comment: @badp since it is a documented feature, if this isn't correct then it would be a [meta-tag:bug]

Comment: @psubsee2003 Is animuson an employee? I forget.

Comment: @badp - Don't you think SE employees have read that post at least once?

Comment: @badp Nope. Elected moderator.

Comment: @badp what Bart said but he didn't add that part to the post, [Clive](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/126857/2) did

Comment: @badp - And it is [reversed correctly](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/52800/kalina?tab=reputation&sort=time) :)

Comment: Then @kalina can probably delete this question.

Comment: @hims056 - I wouldn't say correctly, correctly would have been as per my original post - I still need to gain an additional 100 rep if I want to rep cap and I still have a massive negative red line on my reputation graph = I was still punished. A better implementation of this would have taken the 115 rep off ***yesterday***, not today. Which was the whole point of my question in the first place.

Comment: @Flyk: This answer is actually incorrect and should not be accepted. Voting correction seems buggy in the way you commented. And the FAQ is currently wrong, too. Your comment should be the correct answer. I observed the same: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256224/voting-correction-and-faq-dont-add-up

Comment: @Erwin Nice to see that when people actually pay attention to the words I write rather than the words they assumed I wrote that it turns out I'm not crazy...

Comment: @Flyk: As I now understand, the voting system seems to work as advertised (which would make this answer correct after all - and my comment incorrect). Effective reputation is displayed at http://stackoverflow.com/reputation/ adheres to the published rules. The events depicted in the profile can be rather misleading. In particular, the "Voting corrected" entry in the profile represents the offset resulting from the sum of corrected events to get back in sync with total reputation, not the actual amount deducted for serial upvotes. Daily reputation in the profile is just a historic record.