# Days missing on Epic/Legendy badge progress

Tags: support, reputation, badges, daily-reputation-badges

[My profile on SO.RU > Reputation tab](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176051/discord?tab=reputation)

If you select a wider range, you'll see 9 bars of 200 or more rep: 7 of more than 200 and 2 of exactly 200. However, the badge tracker at the top says, "8/150".

Why?

**[Update]**

The day with confusing results:

[Private log of reputation changes:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPje8.png)
[image]

[Public log of reputation changes:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KkSY.png)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tracker is right. You only have **8** days:

[image]

As seen by [this graph](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176051/discord?tab=reputation&sort=graph) (the line is 200).

Where are the 2 days with exactly 200 rep? I only see one. The next closest is 195.

You've miscounted :)

Comment: Er... I guess it hides downvote-related actions, even on the graph. The day with 195 is displayed as 200 when I'm logged in. The question is then, what's included and excluded, and is there any way to see this without logging out?

Comment: @Discord I see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3KkSY.png). What do you see?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/qiIapH5.png

Comment: hmmm.. that adds up to 200... it must do it according to net change then?

Comment: @Discord does [this page](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/reputation) work on SO.RU?  That should show you exactly how your rep is counted.  The reputation tab in your profile only shows net change per day and can be influenced by other factors (like deleted posts and serial voting reversal) which may count on different days or reversed due to later actions.  The /reputation page shows a better view of what actually counted per day.  it is possible or likely that one of the days you show as +200 didn't actually hit 200.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yet another number, [193](http://pastebin.com/7zQKZzHG). I'm even more confused now. Was this day counted as 193, 195 or 200 rep?

Comment: @Discord whatever on that page is what is basically in the DB for that day.  While the issue isn't the same, take a look at [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256224/voting-correction-and-faq-dont-add-up/256227#256227).  Let me know if that sort of explains your confusion

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks, it makes more sense now. So real reputation changes which count towards daily reputation badges, are displayed only on the `/reputation` page and this is the page I should use to check whether I hit the daily cap?

Comment: @Discord if you want to "audit" your own rep, then use the /reputation page.  If you want to keep track of the changes to your rep, then your profile is sufficient.  But yes, if you want to see what does count towards the various "rep cap" badges, then that is the best page to use.